# How to solve compilation error in converting string to int?

Tags: c

I have written following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() 
{
char a[100];
printf("Enter the string");
scanf("%s",a);
int i = 0;
if(atoi(a[i]) == 2)
{
    printf("Hi");
}
puts(a);
return 0;
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:11:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/stdlib.h:148:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Some time reading the expectations of the various [format specifiers for `scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) would probably reap considerable dividends.

Comment: change `atoi(a[i])` to `atoi(a)`. see the answer below

Comment: For the reader who comes later, the very first version of the code had `int a[100];` in place of the `char a[100];`, but the code was changed/fixed before the 5-minute timer had expired, so it does not show in the edit log (but the answers addressed the original code).

Comment: I made some changes. I have replaced '222' by '2' only. And now tell me what should I do

Comment: The variable i, is not declared anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My input string is '222' and I want to check firsh char from this string with '2'.*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char a[100];
    printf("Enter the string : ");
    scanf("%99s", a);
    if(a[0] == '2') {
        printf("Hi ");
    }
    puts(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%s",a);
```

format %s would expect a string argument. change

```
int a[100];
```

to

```
char a[100];
```

and

```
atoi(a[i]) == 222
```

to

```
atoi(a) == 222
```

Answer (score 2):

You declared your `a` as `int` array, while it should be `char *`, this is not about your conversion code, but variables declaration.

Second, in order to convert a **char** to int, you should use `ord` or simple `int` conversion, `atoi` is used to convert whole `string`, so it should be called on whole `a`: `atoi(a)`

Comment: I have made some changes accordingly and put errors again. please have a look on it

Comment: just read the second part of an answer, it should address the remaining issue.

Answer (score 1):

`atoi(a[i])` gives an error because it needs a pointer variable and `atoi` gets a whole string at time.

Declare your variables like this:

```
char *ch;//then pass in atoi
atoi(a)==2
```

`atoi(*str)` which Interprets an integer value in a byte string pointed to by str.

Answer (score 0):

use this working code now.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() 
{
char a[100];
printf("Enter the string");
scanf("%s",a);
int i = 0;
if(atoi(&a[i]) == 222)
{
   printf("Hi");
}
puts(a);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to use first char from a as an argument for atoi()

Comment: use this statement,
if(atoi(a) == 2)

Comment: no its not working. My input string is '222' and I want to check firsh char from this string with '2'.